# Retrofit api factorisation

Tags: android, retrofit

I was wondering If there was a more readable/maintanable way to write a retrofit interface than how I'm doing it.

I have a same route that can take several parameters, but most of them are the same, I wrote my interface this way :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/questions/{questionid}/response")
Call < QuestionAnswerResponse > postResponse(@Path("questionid") String questionId,
 @Field("course") String courseId,
 @Field("self") String self,
 @Field("hash") String hash,
 @Field("sessionId") String sessionId);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/questions/{questionid}/response")
Call < QuestionAnswerResponse > postResponse(@Path("questionid") String questionId,
 @Field("course") String courseId,
 @Field("self") List < Integer > self,
 @Field("hash") String hash,
 @Field("sessionId") String sessionId);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/polls/{questionid}/response")
Call < QuestionAnswerResponse > postPollResponse(@Path("questionid") String questionId,
 @Field("course") String courseId,
 @Field("self") List < Integer > self,
 @Field("hash") String hash,
 @Field("sessionId") String sessionId);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/questions/{questionid}/response")
Call < QuestionAnswerResponse > postResponse(@Path("questionid") String questionId,
 @Field("course") String courseId,
 @Field("self[text]") String text,
 @Field("self[medias]") List < String > medias,
 @Field("hash") String hash,
 @Field("sessionId") String sessionId);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/polls/{questionid}/response")
Call < QuestionAnswerResponse > postPollResponse(@Path("questionid") String questionId,
 @Field("course") String courseId,
 @Field("self[text]") String text,
 @Field("self[medias]") List < String > medias,
 @Field("hash") String hash,
 @Field("sessionId") String sessionId);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/questions/{questionid}/response")
Call < QuestionAnswerResponse > postResponse(@Path("questionid") String questionId,
 @Field("course") String courseId,
 @Field("self[x]") Integer x,
 @Field("self[y]") Integer y,
 @Field("hash") String hash,
 @Field("sessionId") String sessionId);
```

Note this is just to give you the idea, but there is even more signatures.

The Parameter "Hash" were added and I had to copy/paste it on every call. It didn't feel right :).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide between being descriptive or maintaining code readability.

You can look into [FieldMap](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/FieldMap.html) that will make your calls cleaner, eg:

```java
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/questions/{questionid}/response")
Call < QuestionAnswerResponse > postResponse(@Path("questionid") String questionId,
 @Field("course") String courseId,
 @Field("self") String self,
 @Field("hash") String hash,
 @Field("sessionId") String sessionId);
```

Would change into:

```java
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/questions/{questionid}/response")
Call < QuestionAnswerResponse > postResponse(@Path("questionid") String questionId,
 @FieldMap Map<String, Object> fields);
```

But then you lose the descriptions of fields that may be contained in the call and you need to define the fields somewhere else. Its nice to have this kind of information in one place for future reference, so solution to that might be add commentary the code - but then you clutter your code again :)

What I usually do, is somewhat similar to example above: simplified calls interface for quick summary and below "wrapper" methods for building these calls nicely. For example,

```java
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/questions/{questionid}/response")
Call < QuestionAnswerResponse > postResponse(@Path("questionid") String questionId,
 @FieldMap Map<String, Object> fields);

...

public static void postResponse(String courseId, String self, String hash, String sessionId){
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("course", courseId);
    map.put("self", self);
    map.put("hash", hash);
    map.put("sessionId", sessionId);

    // ... here you build your call with FieldMap params provided

}
```

This way, I have always everything in one place, simplified on top and more detailed somewhere below.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: thank you for having tanken the time to answer me this precisly. From what I understand, I would still have 1 signature with identicals parameters for each call right ? And in each one of them, I would add the field "hash" to tha FieldMap. I was rather looking for a way to "add" a field to a set of fields that are always there. but maybe I can try something with FieldMap

Comment: Well, I see another simple and popular solution here: if you always add a hash to every call, it would be smart to create a request Interceptor. Sorry for not providing example here, but you'll find plenty all over the internet :)

Comment: yes I already have interceptors for some parameters, but I don't think they should be used here.